# jQuery removeClass executing out of order

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT:  I believe I have answered my question, however as I have so little reputation I cannot answer my own questions so soon after posting.  I will mark this as answered when I can.

I am a relatively seasoned programmer, but I am new to JavaScript/jQuery.  I have been searching around and I can't seem to find anything relating to my issue so I figured I would make a post.  Anyway, I have a JavaScript function which takes in a menu and an item.  The item is number which corresponds to a panel of content in `'$content'` that will be switched in or out based on the menu selection, which is also a number that corresponds to a menu option in `'$menuOpt'`.  When I switch out a panel, I have a 'rollOut' animation that rolls the panel out and a 'rollIn' animation that rolls the new panel of content in.  All panels have a default display: none and a `'show'` class is added to the one that is going to be displayed.

prevItem refers to the current panel on display.
itemToShow refers to the panel that is about to be on display.

When I want to roll out the prevItem panel, I add the `'rollOut'` class to prevItem and then remove the `'contentShow'` class so it will go back to having the default display: none so it does not interfere with the layout of the page.  I then add the `'contentShow'` class to itemToShow and then add the `'rollIn'` class so it transitions onto the screen.

My problem is this:  When I add the `'rollOut'` class to the prevItem, it is not rolling out and then disappearing as I intended, it is simply disappearing without having the animation run.  I think this is because `'contentShow'` class is being removed before the `'rollOut'` class is added to the prevItem panel.  The commented out return statement is for testing purposes.  If that return is not commented out, the '`rollOut'` class is correctly applied and works.

```
    $content.removeClass('rollOut');
    $content.eq(prevItem).addClass('rollOut');
    //return;
    $content.eq(prevItem).removeClass('rollIn');
    $content.eq(prevItem).removeClass('contentShow');
    $content.eq(itemToShow).addClass('contentShow');
    $content.eq(itemToShow).addClass('rollIn');
    $content.eq(itemToShow).removeClass('rollOut');

    prevItem = item;

};
```

I've made some edits that I hope clarify the question.

Comment: This is just a small suggestion and not really an answer.  But one thing you could do is to make your elements visible (or not visible) by default and then toggle the class to change their visibility.

Comment: I will do that thank you!  And that is how my panel's are by default; they have a display: none and the contentShow class makes it a display: block.

Comment: So are you talking about CSS transitions with something happening before the transition completes?

Comment: Yeah sort of.  The rollOut animation is never seen by the user, I think this is because the contentShow class is removed before the rollOut class is added, but I have no idea why

Comment: There's a `transitionEnd` event you can hook into. Side note: I doubt that all that code is required to explain your issue. You should take the time to reduce it to a minimal example that fully reproduces the issue.

Comment: If you recreate this problem on http://jsfiddle.net, I will take a look. There is a lot of cleaner ways to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I might be able to, I am never used jsfiddle but I will look into it.

Comment: Don't need jsFiddle or any other off-site demo nearly as much as we need a full yet minimal example directly in the question. You've posted some lines of code, but it isn't a full example with a clear description of the issue.

Comment: Okay I'll go back and try to make it clearer.

Comment: Can't be sure without seeing your CSS, but you probably need to wait to remove `contentShow` until after the `rollOut` animation has *completed*, rather than triggering both class changes one right after the other.   This is almost certainly a CSS problem, not a jQuery problem; post your CSS.

Comment: Yes I think that's the case, I have tried using the .one('webkitAnimationEnd etc', function() {
my removing and adding code goes here
}
and that seems to work but it is very slow.  I will mark this as answered though, because it seems I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question.  The problem was that the css animation was not finishing before I removed the class that allowed that element to be displayed.

Answer (score -2):

This sounds like a problem with how the console works compared to how you (reasonably) expect it to.

`console.log` is very much browser-specific in its implementation. IE8, for example, would always convert its argument to a string, making it quite difficult to debug anything else.

Chrome, however, can be quite clever... and at the same time immensely stupid. I believe Firefox is the same way.

When you `console.log` an element, you actually get the element itself, as a live "thing", that you can see as it updates. This means in particular that the class name will change even as the code executes.

Try `console.log($content.eq(prevItem).attr("class"))` instead, and see if this logs the correct class.

Comment: I will do that and get back to you, thank you. 
EDIT:  I did that and it did indeed print what I expected the class should be.  Unfortunately, that does not solve my problem :(

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck By my understanding, this answer correctly answers why the console was showing what appeared to be the operations happening out of order. That is the question that was asked. While it may not completely solve the problem, it answers the question accurately.